# JQuery On Button Click Alert Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cr33q8v7/

```
$("#findMyWeather").click(function() {
    alert("button clicked");
});
```

All I'm trying to verify is if the JQuery is working and I'm not getting any pop-up that says button clicked, so it would appear the syntax is wrong, but I've checked it multiple times and it looks right.

So if I include the library on JSFiddle, then why does the below code in the HTML file not run, as it appears the function is identical and these pointers both direct to the library:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#findMyWeather").click(function() {
            alert("button clicked");
        });
    </script>
```

So the `//` pointers didn't reference (this is what the teacher instructed).  When I changed to `https:``, then it functioned correctly:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I need another set of eyes, or else I'm missing something else and just don't see it.

Comment: Click in the JavaScript gear and select a jQuery version to include in your fiddle.

Comment: You have not added script library in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't actually include jQuery via a script tag.

e.g. add: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>` to your HMTL

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the *jQuery* library in JSFiddle.
Click the gear that says *Javascript* and choose the version of *jQuery* that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the cdn link for Jquery. Without jquery it will not work. You can add it to the before end of body tag.

Add:`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

you must add below line after last div between `body` tag :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4
/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/taghdisi/h0ag4o40/)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery online by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
 <button id="check">Click on me to check if jquery is working ....!</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#check").click(function(){
  alert("yep, jquery is working");
});


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

every thing looks fine please select jquery in fiddle then try it
and please add this script code in your file
`< script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>`