# How to click on button and alert message in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this code, But didn't work and didn't show alert when i clicked on "Release" button. 
I think my problem for DOM Html and Jquery is ready to use but i Don't solve this problem.

HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td class="noEdit">
          <span id="s1">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn1" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num1" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="2">
        <td>
          <span id="s2">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn2" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num2" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="3">
        <td>
          <span id="s3">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn3" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num3" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ID,tmp_ID,count,flag=0;

    $("tr").click(function()
    {
        ID = $(this).attr('id');
        /*$("#s" + ID).hide();
        $("#num" + ID).show();
        $("#22").show();*/
    });
     $("#"+ID).click(function(){
            alert("button");
        }); 
 });
```

Please, help me for show alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery On Button Click Alert Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180342/jquery-on-button-click-alert-issue)

Comment: Hi, alert work to simply but when i used ID in $("#"+ID), it not worked.

Comment: Have you logged `ID` to the console to check it isn't `undefined`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could listen the onclick event directly on submit buttons and get the "parent tr id" using the jQuery's [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function, which find the "closest" parent with the specified selector (in you case tag = tr).

Please see following:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ID,tmp_ID,count,flag=0;

    $(":submit").click(function()
    {
        ID = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");
        alert("button " + ID);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td class="noEdit">
          <span id="s1">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn1" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num1" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="2">
        <td>
          <span id="s2">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn2" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num2" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="3">
        <td>
          <span id="s3">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn3" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num3" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </script>
</head>
<body>



  <table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td class="noEdit">
              <span id="s1">22</span>
              <div>
              <input id = "btn1" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
              </div>
              <input type="number" id="num1" class="num"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="2">
            <td>
              <span id="s2">22</span>
              <div>
              <input id = "btn2" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
              </div>
              <input type="number" id="num2" class="num"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3" class="3">
            <td>
              <span id="s3">22</span>
              <div>
              <input id = "btn3" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
              </div>
              <input type="number" id="num3" class="num"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
          jQuery("tr>td input[type=submit]").each(function(){
          jQuery(this).on("click",function(){
          console.log("clicked");
        });
        });
        });
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do all that, just listen for a click on your `input[type='submit']` :

```
$(function(){
    var ID,tmp_ID,count,flag=0;

    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        alert("button");
    }); 
});
```

Here is the working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L34eLL40/3/

Comment: Why did you downvoted all the other answers and the question too?

Comment: I downvoted two bad answers. Didn't touch anything else.

Comment: It's really strange, on five answers, just yours isn't downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ID,tmp_ID,count,flag=0;

    $("tr").click(function()
    {
        ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#"+ID).click(function(){
            alert("button with ID="+ID);
        }); 
    });
     
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td class="noEdit">
          <span id="s1">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn1" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num1" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="2">
        <td>
          <span id="s2">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn2" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num2" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="3">
        <td>
          <span id="s3">22</span>
          <div>
          <input id = "btn3" class="num" type="submit" value="Release"/>
          </div>
          <input type="number" id="num3" class="num"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```